# subtract numeric row names to find the smallest absolute value, and define the rest of the row according to the smallest absolute value

Tags: r, shell, awk

So I have two files(space deliminated), the row name of file1 is randomly taken from file2, however, file1 has multiple columns while file2 only has the row name column. I want to regenerate file2, which the rest of the columns of file 2 will be taken from file1, according to the smallest absolute value of subtraction.

For example:

File1:

```
5 0.1 0.2 0.5
20 0.3 0.3 0.6
30 0.5 0.66 0.1
100 0.9 0 1
```

The first column of file1, 5, 20, 30 and 100 all came from file2.

File2:

```
2
5
19
20
27
30
65
100
105
```

This file only has row names. 5, 20 30 and 100 from file 1 is included in this file.

Desired output:

```
2 0.1 0.2 0.5
5 0.1 0.2 0.5
19 0.3 0.3 0.6
20 0.3 0.3 0.6
27 0.5 0.66 0.1
30 0.5 0.66 0.1
65 0.5 0.66 0.1
100 0.9 0 1
105 0.9 0 1
```

Both of files are sorted by column 1 from smallest to largest number. Basically I want each number of file2 to get the rest of the columns from the line which has the smallest absolute value of file1, column1. For example the first number of file2 is 2, and 2 has the smallest absolute value to 5, so that row has the rest of the columns from file1, line of the "5".  If there is a tie, which means two rows has the same absolute value when subtracted, the output will get the columns from the smaller number line. For example 65 from file2, it has equal absolute values from 30 and 100 in file 1, so it will get the value from the 30 line which is smaller.

I was trying to do this in R, and here are my code:

```
i<-1
b<- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
N<- 4 ## number of lines in file1
Row <- 9 ## number of lines in file2
while (i<=Row) {
test <- which(abs(file1[,1] - rep(file2[i,1],N)) == min(abs(file1[,1] - rep(file2[i,1], N)))); ## repeating the value of file2 N times and find the smallest with file1 by subtraction
    if (length(test) == 1) {  ## find 1 smallest value
        a<- file1[test,]; b<-rbind(b, a)
    }
    else if (length(test) == 2) {  ## tie, get the first value, the"smaller one"
        a<- file1[(head(test,1)),]; b<-rbind(b, a)
    } 
    else {warning("There is an error; test is neither 1 or 2")}; i<-i+1
}

output <- b
output$V1 <- NULL
```

It works but extremely slow when my file1 and file2 get really big. Is there a faster way to do this please? All methods are welcomed, awk, shell, R, Perl, python.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I don't think that you are actually referring to `row.names`, but simply the first column in a dataframe. There would be several ways of doing this, but here's one approach:

```
index <- unlist(lapply(File2[,1], function(x) 
  min(which(abs(x - File1[,1]) == min(abs(x - File1[,1]))))))
File2.new <- File1[index,]
File2.new
#      V1  V2   V3  V4
# 1     5 0.1 0.20 0.5
# 1.1   5 0.1 0.20 0.5
# 2    20 0.3 0.30 0.6
# 2.1  20 0.3 0.30 0.6
# 3    30 0.5 0.66 0.1
# 3.1  30 0.5 0.66 0.1
# 3.2  30 0.5 0.66 0.1
# 4   100 0.9 0.00 1.0
# 4.1 100 0.9 0.00 1.0
```

Comment: This saves me great amount of time! Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Reading it without row names makes this much easier. Here is an approach using a helper function:

```
nearest <- function(x, y){
    o <- outer(x,y,function(x,y)abs(x-y))
    a <- apply(o, 1, which.min)
    y[a]
}
```

Reading data:

```
file1 <- read.table(header=FALSE,text="
5 0.1 0.2 0.5
20 0.3 0.3 0.6
30 0.5 0.66 0.1
100 0.9 0 1
")

file2 <- read.table(header=FALSE,text="
2
5
19
20
27
30
65
100
105
")
```

Result:

```
merge(within(file2, {V1_old <- V1; V1 <- nearest(V1, file1$V1)}), file1, all.x=TRUE)

   V1 V1_old  V2   V3  V4
1   5      2 0.1 0.20 0.5
2   5      5 0.1 0.20 0.5
3  20     19 0.3 0.30 0.6
4  20     20 0.3 0.30 0.6
5  30     27 0.5 0.66 0.1
6  30     30 0.5 0.66 0.1
7  30     65 0.5 0.66 0.1
8 100    100 0.9 0.00 1.0
9 100    105 0.9 0.00 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
V1_2 <- unlist(lapply(file2$V1, function(x) file1$V1[which.min(abs(x - file1$V1))]))
file2 <- cbind.data.frame(file2, V1_2)
merge(file2, file1, by.x = "V1_2", by.y = "V1", all.x = TRUE)
```